# Make installation link for enterprise iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, enterprise-distribution

I have an enterprise account and could successfully create .ipa file with this account. Now our partners can install it by putting the `.ipa` file to the iTunes and sync their devices.

I have seen that we can put the .ipa on a direct link and users can download the app from that direct link and install it on their devices.

I upload the .ipa to a server but it is not working. It would be much easier for our partners to use a direct link instead of iTunes and sync. I searched about it too but finding results was not clear. Does some one know what I should do? Should I create the .ipa in other solutions? Or maybe adding some files to the server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to:

1. Decide the URL of the .ipa file on your server
2. Generate a manifest file. Xcode can now do this for you when you export the .ipa for enterprise deployment, or you can create it manually (see link below for details)
3. Place both the manifest and the .ipa on your server
4. Use an URL constructed like this:

   ```
   itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=<url of the manifest>
   ```

The URL should be URL-encoded if necessary.

More details here:

http://help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/apda0e3426d7

However, please note that the Enterprise Developer program only allows you to distribute apps to employees of the company that holds the subscription. If you want to deliver the app to third parties, you should go through the App Store, possibly via the B2B/VPP program to only allow specific customers to get it, or they should be subscribers to the Entreprise Developer program and you should use bundle IDs/certificates/profiles registered on their account. This is valid whether your distribute "over the air" (via a website) or via iTunes.